# Sniff and send UDP traffic using Scapy

Tags: python, sockets, udp, scapy

I followed the tutorial below to implement a packet sniffer in Python:

http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/

On receiving each UDP packet, I would like to send an already saved pcap file (test.pcap). The following snippet shows my implementation:

```
# receive a packet
while True:
  packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

  #packet string from tuple
  packet = packet[0]

  #parse ethernet header
  eth_length = 14

  eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
  eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
  eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
  print 'Destination MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[0:6]) + ' Source MAC : ' + 
    eth_addr(packet[6:12]) + ' Protocol : ' + str(eth_protocol)

  if eth_addr(packet[6:12]) != my_MAC_address:

      #Parse IP packets, IP Protocol number = 8
      if eth_protocol == 8 :
      #Parse IP header
      #take first 20 characters for the ip header
      ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

      #now unpack them :)
      iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

      version_ihl = iph[0]
      version = version_ihl >> 4
      ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

      iph_length = ihl * 4

      ttl = iph[5]
      protocol = iph[6]
      s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
      d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

      print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)


      #UDP packets
      if protocol == 17 :
         u = iph_length + eth_length
         udph_length = 8
         udp_header = packet[u:u+8]

         #now unpack them :)
         udph = unpack('!HHHH' , udp_header)

         source_port = udph[0]
         dest_port = udph[1]
         length = udph[2]
         checksum = udph[3]

         print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Length : ' + str(length) + ' Checksum : ' + str(checksum)

         h_size = eth_length + iph_length + udph_length
         data_size = len(packet) - h_size

         #get data from the packet
         data = packet[h_size:]

         print 'Data : ' + data
         my_pkt = rdpcap("test.pcap")
         sendp(my_pkt)
```

Test.pcap contains a UDP packet with UDP_src=7777 and UDP_dest=9999.

Traffic is generated using netcat as follows:

```
nc -u -p 7777 ip_dst_addr 9999
```

The sniffer can receive only first netcat msg and send test.pcap in response. But subsequent netcat msgs are not received at all. However, using any other combination of UDP ports in netcat, the sniffer works fine. For example: running netcat as:

```
nc -u -p 8888 ip_dst_addr 9999
```

there is no problem and I am able to send test.pcap in response to each UDP packet/msg.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scapy has several built-in sniffers, that are really easy to use.

> ```
> >>> help(sniff)
> Help on function sniff in module scapy.arch.windows.compatibility:
>
> sniff(count=0, store=1, offline=None, prn=None, stop_filter=None, lfilter=None, L2socket=None, timeout=None, *arg, **karg)
>     Sniff packets
>     sniff([count=0,] [prn=None,] [store=1,] [offline=None,] [lfilter=None,] + L2ListenSocket args) -> list of packets
>     Select interface to sniff by setting conf.iface. Use show_interfaces() to see interface names.
>       count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity
>       store: whether to store sniffed packets or discard them
>         prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned,
>              it is displayed. Ex:
>              ex: prn = lambda x: x.summary()
>      filter: provide a BPF filter
>     lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine
>              if further action may be done
>              ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
>     offline: pcap file to read packets from, instead of sniffing them
>     timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None)
>     L2socket: use the provided L2socket
>     stop_filter: python function applied to each packet to determine
>                  if we have to stop the capture after this packet
>                  ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
> ```

Which means you could simply do:

```
packets = rdpcap("test.pcap")
sniff(lfilter=lambda x: x.haslayer(UDP) and x[Ether].src==sending_mac and x[UDP].sport==port, prn=lambda x: send(packets))
```

This will append all UDP packets to the test.pcap file

Comment: Thanks, your implementation is much simpler. 

But the problem still persists that sniffer can't sniff packets when we send test.pcap using same udp ports as in the client msg. :/

Comment: Do you want to sniff the packets you have send ? Otherwise that should be working :/ Don't really understand your problem

Comment: I don't want to sniff outgoing pkts in the sniffer. That's why there is the following if condition:
       if eth_addr(packet[6:12]) != my_MAC_address

There are two kind of packets:
1) requests that I would like to sniff. It can be generated using netcat. Let's say UDP_src=7777 and UDP_dst=9999
2) response which in our case is test.pcap. I don't want to sniff response packets. test.pcap contains one UDP packet with UDP_src=7777 and UDP_dst=9999

Upon receiving the first request, i can send test.pcap. But afterwards it can't sniff pkts with UDP_src=7777 and UDP_dst=9999

Comment: In the above case, both request and response use same UDP ports. However, by using a different combination of ports, everything works fine. For example, for requests= (UDP_src=8888, UDP_dst=9999) . And for response=(UDP_src=7777, UDP_dst=9999).

Comment: thanks, the issue has been resolved. There was an underlying problem in my network